# Custom Layout Using Keyboard & Custom UTF Characters

Tags: android, utf-8, emoji, custom-keyboard

I am making a soft-keyboard using KeyboardView and want to use a relative layout so I can have other things as well as keys. I also want to use other UTF characters such as emojis. I used https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example as reference on how to use the KeyboardView.

This is my keyboard.xml file. How could I approach this? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="33%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/act">

        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</Keyboard>
```